# Model View Controller: Can the Model access the view directly?

Tags: design, mvc, code-quality, coding-standards, modeling

According to my understanding,  in the MVC design the *Model* can only receive the functions calls from the *Controller* and not from the *View* directly.

Is it true that the *Model* can change or access the *View* directly?

Comment: How would that look? Do you have code samples?

Comment: I dared to slightly edit the text to put the question at the end. I also highlighted the MVC components, since you refer to them in a very precise manner. I hope that you can agree with it.

Comment: The model is a piece of data ... it doesn't really call functions or receive function calls

Answer (score 2):

The View knows about the model and can call its properties, fields and methods as required. Not sure if you would call that "receive function calls"?

The Model doesn't know about the view so can't call it directly

The Controller knows about the Model and the View and can affect both, although its usual not to call the view directly.

Comment: Not it's clear to me. thank you Mr. @Ewan

Comment: It might be worth adding that while the View can access the Model, it should do so only in a read-only manner. The View is not allowed/supposed to make changes to the Model.

Answer (score 2):

There are several flavors of MVC.

In the [original concept](http://heim.ifi.uio.no/~trygver/themes/mvc/mvc-index.html) published 1979, the view queries the model and the model doesn’t know about the views. However constant polling is not so efficient.

Subsequent [MVC designs](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller) therefore generally see the view as an [observer](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_pattern) of the model. This means that views subscribe to the model and get notified of changes. The model does not know that it’s a view and can not use the full view’s interface. You’ll find an in-depth analysis of the MVC relationships in [GoF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Design_Patterns) (page 4 to 6).

Comment: For the ignorant but interested: What's _GoF_?

Comment: @Aganju Oh! Sorry! GoF stands for "Gang of Four".  It refers to the seminal book "Design patterns" by Gamma, Helm, Johnson & Vlissides (the 4 authors).  I added a hyperlink in my answer to clarify.

Comment: If you mention "several flavors of MVC", don't forget the "web flavor", where there is no connection between the Model and the View and all interaction goes via the Controller.

Comment: @BartvanIngenSchenau very good remark! In fact this is was the driving factor behind Talligent’s [MVP architecture](http://www.wildcrest.com/Potel/Portfolio/mvp.pdf), the P being this pass-through controller